# conditional rendering with toast and usestate does not work with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my state and I want to display the component if the value is true but in the console I receive the error message Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state my code

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";

const Index = () => {

  const [test, setTest]= useState(true);
  const { addToast } = useToasts();

  function RenderToast() {

    return (
      <div>
        { addToast('message') }
      </div>
    )}

    return (
      <div>
        {test &&  <RenderToast /> }
      </div>
    )

  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set state *during* a render. And I'm guessing that `addToast` internally sets some state.

And looking at [the docs for that library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toast-notifications), you don't explicitly render the toasts. You just call `addToast` and then the `<ToastProvider/>` farther up in the tree shows them.

So to make this simple example works where a toast is shown on mount, you should use an effect to add the toast after the first render, and make sure your component is wrapped by `<ToastProvider>`

```
const Index = () => {
  const { addToast } = useToasts();

  useEffect(() => {
    addToast('message')
  }, [])

  return <>Some Content here</>
}

// Example app that includes the toast provider
const MyApp = () => {
  <ToastProvider>
    <Index />
  </ToastProvider>
}
```

---

> how i can display the toast based on a variable for exemple display toast after receive error on backend?

You simply call `addToast` where you are handling your server communication.

For example:

```
const Index = () => {
  const { addToast } = useToasts();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataFromApi()
      .then(data => ...)
      .catch(error => addToast(`error: ${error}`))
  }, [])

  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but how i can display the toast based on a variable for exemple display toast after receive error on backend

Comment: You just call `adToast` when you want to show it. See my updated answer.

Comment: hi thank you for your answer I have already done this what I wanted is to centralize the errors in a separate file and to use it after an error in the fetch with the possibility of passing parameters like the statuscode to better change by example the color of the toast.Thank you for your answer